# How do I put custom fonts into HTML5 Canvas easily?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

When looking through the questions I never found a clear answer to the above. I wanted a method that worked with just about every platform. So for the benefit of the community, I thought I'd share my success in getting custom fonts to work in canvas. My main question was, What is a surefire way to get said fonts to work? I tried multiple methods such as just using a CSS stylesheet but it's a bit more complicated than that. Here's what I found:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use custom fonts in an HTML5 Canvas element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608022/how-can-i-use-custom-fonts-in-an-html5-canvas-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll discuss my code underneath.
First off, My Javascript:

```
window.onload = function start() {
            canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
            C_Width = canvas.width;
            C_Height = canvas.height;
            cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
            setTimeout(text_handler,200);
        }

        function text_handler() {
        console.log('made it!');
        cxt.font="20px myFont";//font size and then font family.
        cxt.fillStyle="white"; //color to be seen on a black canvas, default is black text
        cxt.fillText("TEST",(C_Width/2-200),C_Height/2); //cxt.fillText("message",x_coord,y_coord);
        }
```

Allow me to explain whats going on here. I have a simple `window.onload` function so that the canvas exists before I try to get its Id and Context. Inside my `text_handler()` function, I have the font size and the font family defined in one line, as well as my font color (White because I have a black canvas). Then in the canvas I draw my message, and provide an x coordinate and a y coordinate. The `setTimeout();` delay may be necessary in order to give the canvas time to load the font. In the test program I wrote, I actually got the delay time down really low, though 100ms is almost unnoticeable.
Another critical part of this is the CSS stylesheet:

```
canvas {
            background-color: black; //for white text
            font-family:myFont; //necessary
        }
        #load {
            font-family:myFont; //necessary to load font with div
            visibility: hidden; //makes div invisible but the div element forces the text to load before the canvas.
            height: 0px;
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family:myFont; 
            src: url('./Font_Path.ttf');
            } //self-explanatory
```

I have of course defined the font in the canvas, the body of the webpage, and a necessary hidden div. The div helps load the font. I have styles in order that the div remains invisible but it still does its job. For some reason, through my testing, I determined that the `font-family` style must be above the other styles in my div. Of course, you could use whatever you want. Also of course, I use `@font-face` for my custom font.

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<body>
    <div id="load">words</div> <!-- load font -->
    <canvas id="canvas1" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
</body>
```

As explained above, the div is necessary to load the font before the canvas can implement it. That's why I have "words" inside it.

I really hope this helps someone out because I simply couldn't find anything on it. Please ask me questions, tell me what I could have done differently in the comment section below, or just simply ways I can simplify my code. I'd appreciate the help and constructive criticism. Thanks, and happy Canvas-ing...

Comment: Also one last thing I forgot to mention. A delay might be necessary before calling the `text_handler()` function.

Comment: Would **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28591573/how-i-write-an-icon-in-the-context-canvas/28593478#28593478)** work for your scenario?

Comment: Nice work. The delay you mention in your comment is quite important. You might take a look at @KenFyrstenberg's link on how to deal with waiting until the font is fully loaded before the code tries to make use of it in the canvas. ;-)

Answer (score 15):

Update: This solution [now works](https://caniuse.com/?search=fontface%20api) on all browsers except IE 11 and below.

Although it doesn't have complete support yet you can now use the [FontFace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FontFace) API to explicitly load fonts before using them on a canvas.

```
var f = new FontFace('Font name', 'url(/path/to/font.ttf)');

f.load().then(function(font) {

  // Ready to use the font in a canvas context
  console.log('font ready');

  // Add font on the html page
  document.fonts.add(font);

  ctx.font = '48px Font name';
  ctx.strokeText('Hello world', 100, 100);

});
```

I can confirm that this works on Chrome 61.0.3163.100, Safari 11.0 (12604.1.38.1.7), Firefox 56.0 (all OSX) and Safari iOS 11.1.

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer.

Comment: this didn't work for me until i changed the `f.load()` line to `f.load().then(function(font) {
  document.fonts.add(font);`

Comment: Man thanks alot this helped me alot, I got the same code from everywhere but it didn't work, but after then i saw this answer and `document.fonts.add(font);` this line was missing from everywhere

Answer (score 0):

An important point that might get lost is that each font that is used on canvas must also be loaded by setting the font-family style-attribute for the canvas element.

Here's my version using jquery. The ready event removes the need for any timeouts.

```
<head>
 <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'AlexBrush';
      src: url('fonts/AlexBrush-Regular.ttf');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Pacifico';
      src: url('fonts/Pacifico.ttf');
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <canvas id='testCanvas' width='1200px' height='800px'></canvas>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('#testCanvas').css('font-family', "AlexBrush");
        $('#testCanvas').css('font-family', "Pacifico");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
        ctx.font = "100px AlexBrush";
        ctx.fillText('Hello World', 100, 300);
        ctx.font = "100px Pacifico";
        ctx.fillText('Hello World', 100, 500);
    })
  </script>
</body>
```